# Html to pdf Unicode chars not being displayed in pdfptable

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I am writing a pdf file from html markup. In my code snippet the pdf is being successfully generated and the unicode characters are being also being rendered on the table. 
**Here is my code snippet:**

```
void GeneratePdfFromHtml()
{
    const string outputFilename = @"c:\report.pdf";
    const string inputFilename = @"C:\report.html";

    using (var input = new FileStream(inputFilename, FileMode.Open))
    using (var output = new FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        CreatePdf(input, output);
    }
}
```

and this method creates pdf with unicode support:

```
void CreatePdf(Stream htmlInput, Stream pdfOutput)
{
    using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30))
    {
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, pdfOutput);
        var worker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();

        document.Open();

        worker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlInput, null, Encoding.Unicode, new UnicodeFontFactory());

        document.Close();
    }
}
```

This is a helper class to provide required fonts:

```
public class UnicodeFontFactory : FontFactoryImp
{
    private static readonly string FontPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
          "ARIALUNI.ttf");

    private readonly BaseFont _baseFont;

    public UnicodeFontFactory()
    {
        _baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(FontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

    }

    public override iTextSharp.text.Font GetFont(string fontname, string encoding, bool embedded, float size, int style, BaseColor color,
          bool cached)
    {
        return new iTextSharp.text.Font(_baseFont, size, style, color);
    }
}
```

**Problem** this draws the resultant contents on Pdf document page but I want this to be drawn in a pdfptable cell.

**What I have tried to achieve this:**

```
void CreatePdf(string htmltext)
{
    using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30))
    {
        document.Open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        List<IElement> elementsIzv = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(htmltext, null);
        foreach (IElement e in elementsIzv)
        {
            cell.AddElement(e);
        }
        table.AddCell(cell);
        document.Add(table);

        document.Close();
    }
}
```

This snippet truncates the Special Characters. Please direct me in the right way, Any replacement to itextsharp is also acceptable.

Comment: I hope this may help https://gist.github.com/dedico/1567859

Comment: Why would you put `iText7` tag on the question? This question doesn't have anything to do with iText7.

Comment: @AlexeySubach itextpdf support suggested me to post a question here and in the tags field write itext or itext7. Please read **Where to post my question** Guidelines here http://itextpdf.com/support

Comment: @COUT, the idea is that you should put `itext` tag for iText5-related questions and `itext7` for iText7-related ones :)

Comment: I understand @AlexeySubach, Thank you :)

Comment: can you guide me to the solution of above problem ?

Comment: As for replacement, I would recommend to try out iText7 and pdfHTML add-on.

Comment: It would help if you posted a snippet of `HTML` so we can see the offending format and see how the Unicode text is being truncated when converted to PDF.